# mergetool says “No files need merging”, but there is ACTUAL PHYSICAL conflict markup in files

Tags: git-pull, merge-conflict-resolution

After a git pull with conflicts, git mergetool tells me that "No files need merging", even though in some files for which conflicts were reported there is now ***ACTUAL*** ***PHYSICAL*** conflict markup present.

Also, I am absolutely positive that I really, really haven't actually committed the merge markup earlier. I have checked every which way for this possibility and it is simply not the case.

What gives?

Comment: What does `git status` tell you?  I'll bet it reports the correct information.  As a rule of thumb, the buck stops with what Git says directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this happens if you run git mergetool in a subdirectory of your repository root rather than in the repo root itself. It might be a bug in the specific merge tool I am using (kdiff3). Changing directory to repo root completely resolves the issue.